# Uploading a file from HTML form with Flask and Boto3

Tags: python, html, amazon-s3, flask, boto3

I want to directly uploading a file to S3 from an HTML form without saving it to the server first. I'm using Boto3 and Flask. The Flask and HTML code is posted below. I tested the connection to S3 so there has to be a problem with my HTML form. The error says "Filename must be a string". Thanks for your help.

Flask:

```
.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    try:
        latestfile = request.form.get('filetoupload')
        conn = boto3.client('s3', region_name="eu-west-1", endpoint_url="example.com", aws_access_key_id='the access key here', aws_secret_access_key='the secret key here',)
        conn.create_bucket(Bucket="mytestbucket22")
        bucket_name = "mytestbucket22"
        conn.upload_file(latestfile, bucket_name, latestfile)
        return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.username, sumsg="Upload done!")
    except Exception as ermsg:
        print(ermsg)
        return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.username, ermsg=ermsg)
```

HTML:

```
<form action="./upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="filetoupload" type="file">
    <button type="submit" class="buttonformatting" onclick="showImage();">Download</button></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the uploaded file from the Flask request you can upload it using the **conn.upload_fileobj()** method. You are now using **conn.upload_file()** which expects a filename that points to a file on disk.

Do something like

```
file = request.files['filefield']
conn.upload_fileobj(file, 'mybucket', 'mykey')
```

More documentation and information:

The Flask request object gives you a **FileStorage** object behaves like a regular Python file: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.files

Read up on the Boto3 documentation here: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj

Comment: It returns `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`, didnt worked

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a form with a signed policy as documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

You can use this Flask utility to do the signature generation for you:
https://github.com/fastmonkeys/pontus

Copy-pasting from the example on their website, to generate the form field values:
(it's up to you to put that in an HTML form):

```
import boto3
from flask import current_app
from pontus import AmazonS3SignedRequest

session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=current_app.config.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    aws_secret_access_key=current_app.config.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
)
bucket = session.resource('s3').Bucket('testbucket')

signed_request = AmazonS3SignedRequest(
    key_name=u'my/file.jpg',
    mime_type=u'image/jpeg',
    bucket=bucket,
    session=session
)

signed_request.form_fields
```